# Multiple OR Strings

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, return-value

I cannot find out how to pass multiple strings in an If statement.

Here is my Code :

```
    var date = new Date();

    if (document.getElementById("postcode-entry").value == ("G74" || "G75")) {
        if (date.getHours() < 8 ) {
            window.alert("Sorry we are not open at the moment, please try again later.");
        } else {
            window.open("http://http://stackoverflow.com");
        }
    } else {
        window.alert("Sorry we do not Delivery to your area, please collect from store");
    }
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase `("G74" || "G75")` forces a boolean evaluation on each string, and both will return true always.

So you would need to do something like this:

```
var myvar = document.getElementById("postcode-entry").value;

if(myvar === "G74" || myvar === "G75")
```

Comment: Thanks Faust, such a massive help!

Answer (score 2):

i am not sure if you want to follow this approach but try using  the following-

```
var strArr = [ 'G74', 'G75' ];

if( strArr.indexOf( document.getElementById("postcode-entry").value ) !== -1 ) {
// Your  normal code goes  here
}
```

Using this, you can have n number of string tested in a single statement inside if.

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
 var post_code = document.getElementById("postcode-entry").value;
  if (post_code == "G74" || post_code == "G75")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this before. Perhaps you can use the switch statement

But in your case I would recomment the following:

```
var poscode = document.getElementById("postcode-entry").value
if (postcode === "G74" || postcode === "G75") ......
```