# Multiple "OR" strings in sSearch

Tags: sql, regex, string, search, datatables

This searches my WPDataTable and filters it to only display rows containing 'apple':

```
function filterGlobalSearch( $tableDescriptionObj, $tableId , $wpDataTablesObj)   {
    if( $tableId == 1 ){
        $tableDescriptionObj->dataTableParams->oSearch = array(
            'bSmart' => false,
            'bRegex' => false,
            'sSearch' => 'apple'
        );
    }
    return $tableDescriptionObj;
}
add_filter('wpdatatables_filter_table_description','filterGlobalSearch', 10, 3);
```

Please can you tell me how to search for **'apple' OR 'banana'**?  (to show rows that contain either word).

I've found similar answers on StackExchange and other forums about multiple OR strings (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656164/multiple-or-strings)) but can't seem to get them working.

Have already tried:

```
'apple|banana'
'apple||banana'
'apple'|'banana'
'apple'||'banana'
'apple' OR 'banana'
array('apple', 'banana')
```

Grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been provided a working solution that I'll share here:

**'bRegex' => false** should be changed to **true**.

**'apple|banana'** is the search string.